# How to have termite background transparency without text being affected?

Tags: i3-wm, transparency, compton

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with i3 and Compton compositor. Now I installed termite and I really want a transparent background. which I can achieve by adding this in my termite config

```
[colors]
background = rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

However this also makes the text within the terminal transparent which is hard on the eyes and makes some text not really legible. Only everyone just says that this way the text shouldn't be transparent.

Do any of you have an idea why the text is affected?

Regards